# How can I find the complexity of this problem: recursive function in loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, analytics

When I solves analysis I face a problem when calculate the exact complexity about this code:

```
Function1(A[], L, S[])  {
      if (L == N) 
           return true
      for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
          if (S[i] == false) {
              if (!Check(A, L, i)) {          
                  A[L] = i;
                  S[i] = true;
                  Function1(A, L+1, S);
                  S[i] = false;
              }                                       
         }    
     }    
}
Check(A[], L, R) 
{
     for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
          if (abs(L - i) == abs(A[i] - R))
              return true;
     } 
     return false; 
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to find the complexity of the code is to use a large input and count the calculations that take place. It's called the Big (O) notation.

Comment: What is `N`? Size of `A` and `S`?

Comment: n is the size of 2 array

Comment: "How can I find the complexity of this problem": if inputs is doubled in size, how does the running time change? It doubles? Less than double? More than double? You will first of course need to explain, and specify here, what is your variable input, and what is fixed. You also have tools that compute the McCabe complexity index which is another indicator.

Comment: @saramohsen It is all depends on init values. It could be from O(n^2) to O(n^n * n!)